# How to export an animated object from Blender to an .usdz-file for Reality Composer (AR)?

Tags: animation, export

I'm totally new to Blender.

I only need it to make a rectangle with an animation that extrudes or scales over one axis over time.
So I keyframed X-Scale of a rectangle and tried to export it in an .abc-file, then tried to convert it to a .usdz-file via my terminal.
[image: like here]

But when I do this I only get a simple cube without animation and without material.[image: like this]

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

export animated .DAE file first, and then open with Xcode, Xcode allows you export .USDZ file, this step works great for me, hope it helps.